# MySQL update column with Python

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to update three columns in my table with data by using Python variables, but I have ran into an issue which I don't seem to understand.

I have done some amendments but still run into issues, can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

**My table:**

```
Columns   id   code    url       val1    val2    val3
Data      1    A2941   url.com   NULL    NULL    NULL
```

**My query:**

```
cursor.execute("UPDATE mytable SET val1=%s", (myVar))
```

**Error message:**

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s' at line 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`execute` takes a tuple as its second argument. `(myVar)` is just the `myVar` variable surrounded in parenthesis. To create a tuple that contains only `myVar`, you need to add a comma:

```py
cursor.execute("UPDATE mytable SET val1=%s", (myVar,))
# Here --------------------------------------------^
```